# Babel source code not working

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I may have missed something somewhere but I can't make babel work !

I have installed and enabled correctly python-mode and in org mode I enter the begin_src section by completing .

Everything stay grey and it with no code indentation, it seems that python isn't recognize.

In my .emacs I have loaded python for babel :

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((emacs-lisp . t)
   (python . t)
   ))
```

The org file section looks like this :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC: python
def hello( ):
    print "hello"
#+END_SRC
```

I haven't seen it working on my computer yet and I keep dreaming of it every night !

Is there any org hero in the area ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t
    org-src-preserve-indentation t
    org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
```

in your init file. This should give you syntax highlighting, allow you to indent as you would in `python-mode`, and preserve those indents when if you export. Also, get rid of the `:` after `BEGIN_SRC`. So your example should be:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
def hello():
    print "hello"
#+END_SRC
```

On my computer, with those options it looks like:[image]

And notice, I am still in `org-mode` :) With your cursor at the end of the src block, you can hit `C-x C-e` to evaluate your `hello` function, and print the result in the echo area at the bottom of your frame!

Comment: So cool ! It works !

Thank you, you made my dream come true :D

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Now that you can use source code blocks in `org-mode` the way you want, now it's time to do your whole init file in `org-mode`, haha! : )

Comment: I began to configure emacs since about two weeks, now it's like a hobby ! cheers